# Getting map using C# code in ArcMap?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, c#

I have been programming in C# a small code for:1) create a polyline Featureclass in a GDB, 2)put that in the map view (ArcMap 10.2) and finally 3) edit that feature using a button or tool...
Well I have tried to program it using AddInns controls, but I faced the trouble at the time to edit the feature; I switch to use "Extending ArcObjects" now I can create the feature in my local GDB easily, but at the momento to put the Feature into the map I can not do it; the code is as follows:

```
GLB.nombre = txtNombre.Text;//definig the name from a text box in a regular form....
IWorkspaceFactory pWorkSpaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();
IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)pWorkSpaceFactory.OpenFromFile(@"C:\INFO_2015\ANH_GDB.gdb", 0);
IFeatureDataset featureDataset = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureDataset("Temp");

IFeatureClass featureClass;

UID CLSID = new UIDClass();
UID CLSEXT = null;
CLSID.Value = "esriGeoDatabase.Feature";
IObjectClassDescription objectClassDescription = new FeatureClassDescriptionClass();

IGeometryDef pGeoDefL = new GeometryDefClass();
var pGeoDefEditL = (IGeometryDefEdit)pGeoDefL;
pGeoDefEditL.GeometryType_2 = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline;

//here I define the fields of the DB.......
IFields fields = new FieldsClass();
fields = objectClassDescription.RequiredFields;
IFieldsEdit fieldsEdit = (IFieldsEdit)fields; // Explicit Cast
fieldsEdit.FieldCount_2 = 3;
// ID Field
IField oIdFieldL = new FieldClass();
var oIdFieldEditL = (IFieldEdit)oIdFieldL; // Explicit Cast
oIdFieldEditL.Name_2 = "ObjectID";
oIdFieldEditL.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID;
fieldsEdit.set_Field(0, oIdFieldL);
//Entity type
IField shpFieldL = new FieldClass();
var shpFieldEditL = (IFieldEdit)shpFieldL; // Explicit Cast
shpFieldEditL.Name_2 = "Shape";
shpFieldEditL.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry;
shpFieldEditL.GeometryDef_2 = pGeoDefL;
fieldsEdit.set_Field(1, shpFieldL);
//line lenght
IField longFieldL = new FieldClass();
var longFieldEditL = (IFieldEdit)longFieldL;
longFieldEditL.Name_2 = "Longitud";
longFieldEditL.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble;
fieldsEdit.set_Field(2, longFieldL);
// add field to field collection
fields = fieldsEdit; // Explicit Cast

IFieldChecker fieldChecker = new FieldCheckerClass();
IEnumFieldError enumFieldError = null;
IFields validatedFields = null;
fieldChecker.ValidateWorkspace = (IWorkspace)featureWorkspace;
fieldChecker.Validate(fields, out enumFieldError, out validatedFields);

featureClass = featureDataset.CreateFeatureClass(GLB.nombre, validatedFields, CLSID, CLSEXT, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "Shape", "");

IApplication application;//HERE IS THE ERROR!!!!!!!!
IMxDocument mxDocument = ((IMxDocument)(application.Document)); // Explicit Cast
IActiveView activeView = mxDocument.ActiveView;
IMap map = activeView.FocusMap;

IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(GLB.nombre);
featureLayer.Name = GLB.nombre;
map.AddLayer(featureLayer);

mxDocument.UpdateContents();
mxDocument.ActiveView.Refresh();
```

I have been working on it more than three weeks without solution, could anybody give me a hand?

Comment: IApplication application = (IApplication) ArcMap.Application; the ArcMap application is type IMXApplication so it needs to be cast to an IApplication object. This is only for Esri Addin type projects.

Comment: Yes, if I use ADDINS projects, the code you wrote, works nicely, but as I told in my question I have developing an "Extended ArcObject" application, and it does not work at all.

Comment: I am about to leave the project, I have understood that there is no way to do it through "Extending ArcObjects" because I have been trying many ways to do it and nothing works; well I solved the problem, really easily, using ADD-INS control... so now I have facing another problem I will share to you in another question........

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your application variable to reference the application.
In old school ArcObjects this done through the hook provided by your control that implements ICommand or ITool etc.

```
   public override void OnCreate(object hook)
    {
      _application = hook as IApplication;
      //get the editor environment
      UID editorUid = new UID();
      editorUid.Value = "esriEditor.Editor";
      _editor = m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUid) as IEditor;
    }
```

In add-ins you can use the ArcMap keyword to get at the application. The example below is in the tools constructor method.

```
public CCTool()
{
  //get the editor environment
  UID editorUid = new UID();
  editorUid.Value = "esriEditor.Editor";
  _editor = ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorUid) as IEditor;
}
```

The above examples are for code within an ArcMap Application. If you have a stand-alone application that drives ArcMap then you can use the code referenced in the Esri help topic [Automating ArcGIS for Desktop applications](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Automating_the_ArcGIS_Desktop_applications/0001000001nn000000/). This shows how to start ArcMap and get a reference to IApplication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that in the code line after where the error is C# marks "application" and tells me: "Local variable 'application' might not be initialized before accesing"; I have try to initialize the variable like:

Comment: IApplication application = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication;//does not work
IApplication application = new AppRefClass();//doesn't either

Comment: I have not working with addins, in addins I have no problem with this; I am building an app "Extending ArcObjects", so it has a different treatment. In addins is simple, you only have to write the code like:

IApplication application = ArcMap.Application;

Comment: Finally I have understood that there is no way to do it through "Extending ArcObjects" because I have been trying many ways to do it and nothing works; well I solved the problem, really easily, using ADD-INS control... so now I have facing another problem I will share to you in another question........

Comment: SeaJunk that *is* old school, doing it that way is being depreciated in favor of addins. Can you extend that to show the *new & improved* addin way and show how to tell the difference?

Comment: Second example shows the the add-in pattern. Regardless I'll update the answer with a reference to the desktop automation help, which i think is more what Oscar was after originally.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the map in "Extending ArcObjects" using below code:

```
 Type typ = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(typeof(AppRefClass).GUID);
 System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
 IApplication app = obj as IApplication;
 IMap map = (app.Document as IMxDocument).FocusMap;
```

Check this http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriFramework/AppRef.htm

If the extending ArcObject type is command you can get the application object from "OnCreate" method(defaultly created) of BaseCommand where application is from the hook object.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when this command is created
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hook">Instance of the application</param>
    public override void OnCreate(object hook)
    {
        if (hook == null)
            return;

        m_application = hook as IApplication;

        //Disable if it is not ArcMap
        if (hook is IMxApplication)
            base.m_enabled = true;
        else
            base.m_enabled = false;

        // TODO:  Add other initialization code
    }
```